# PowerShell Find Members of Two Specific AD Groups

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have AD groups called ADGroup1 and ADGroup2.  I know I can see a list of each by querying:

`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup1`

or

`Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "ADGroup2`

But does anyone have a quick way for me to find all users that belong to both of the groups?

Comment: are you looking for objects exclusively members of both or just to list the members of both ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I'm looking to get members are that exclusively members of both groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get this via [LDAP Filtering](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) with some string manipulation to automatically generate the LDAP Filters:

```
# Create a filter to get all groups in `$groups`
$groups = 'ADGroup1', 'ADGroup2'
$groupFilter = '(|'
$groups | ForEach-Object {
    $groupFilter += '(samAccountName={0})' -f $_
}
$groupFilter += ')'

# create a new filter to get all objects "members of" the groups, exclusive
# change to `(|` for inclusive
$memberOfFilter = '(&'
# get the `DistinguishedName` of all groups and build the filter
(Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $groupFilter).DistinguishedName |
    ForEach-Object { $memberOfFilter += '(memberof={0})' -f $_ }
$memberOfFilter += ')'
# use this one to find only users:
#     $memberOfFilter += '(objectclass=user)(objectcategory=person))'
# instead of:
#     $memberOfFilter += ')'
# or just use `Get-ADUser` instead of `Get-ADObject`


# get all objects "members of" all groups in `$groups`
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter $memberOfFilter
```

Comment: That is absolutely beautiful!

Comment: Seriously!  I have a customer who uses LDAP for authentication to our application.  I have repeatedly told them that users can only belong to one of the AD groups for authentication, and if they belong to multiple it causes a conflict.  I just ran this and verified there are about 300 users who belong to multiple, thus can never log in... Even though they've repeatedly told me they're not doing this...

Comment: @ChristopherCass customers be customers . Btw you can use this same logic for more than 2 groups, it will work with 3 or more groups too.

Comment: If I did it for more than two groups, I would still want to see any combination where they were in more than one, not necessarily all the groups.

Comment: @ChristopherCass yeah that gets a bit tricky because LDAP filtering is either inclusive (any condition is true) or exclusive (all conditions are true) but if you have such problem you could try to solve it and ask a new question here if needing help, i'll try to help

Comment: Right now this gets me pretty far.  There are rarely more than 3 AD groups involved, and it's not hard to query all of them in combinations of 2.  Thanks again for the help!